# Subtraction and division operation with varargs and for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, dynamic, args

I am a beginner in var args (and programming too) and I have no idea what the subtraction and division methods could look like using them for the loop. Thanks for the help :) I have this but I know it doesn't work;

```
public int dynamicSub(int... n) {
    int result = 0;
    for (int i : n) {
    result = result - i;
    }
    return result;
}
public int dynamicDivision(int... n) {
    int result = 0;
    for (int i : n) {
    result = result / i;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: What doesn't work? What is the expected output? The division method will simply return 0 (unless you divide by 0, which will throw an exception).

Comment: You should reserve the first parameter of both methods to be the initial (or left-most) value. So `dynamicSub(int initial, int... n)` and `dynamicDivision(int initial, int... n)`.

Answer (score 0):

Your subtraction works well. You just have to decide whether result is always supposed to start with 0.

```
int result = dynamicSub(12, 15, 18); // returns -45
```

Here is a slightly modified version of your division method. It avoids division by 0 and you can hand in a start value for result.

```
public int dynamicDivision(int start, int... n) {
    int result = start;
    for (int i : n) {
        if(i != 0 && result != 0) {
            result = result / i;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Using this new version of the method the result is, in my following example, 3.

> 1000 is the start value of result.
>
> 0, 15, 18 are values result gets divided by.

```
int result = dynamicDivision(1000, 0, 15, 18); // result is 3
```